# How to do an insert with blocks of selects?

Tags: mysql

What i'm doing is a simple insert using a select statement to retrieve data from other tables, and here is the problem, i want to do that insert but with multiple inserts trying to imitate a insert with block insertion in fact, if i run the code below it works but just for one row:

```
INSERT INTO factmonitoreo (idEstacion, IdVariable, IdTiempoRegistro, Valor, ValorOriginal, FlagRegistro) 
(SELECT dt.idEstacion, dv.IdVariable, '2007-01-01 00:04:29', 0, 0, 0
FROM dimestacion AS dt 
INNER JOIN dimtipoestacion AS dte ON dt.IdTipoEstacion = dte.IdTipoEstacion 
JOIN dimvariable AS dv 
WHERE dt.Estacion LIKE 'El Lago' 
AND dte.CodTipoEstacion LIKE 'ECT' 
AND dv.ColumnNameToManualUpdateFromCSV LIKE 'Temperatura')
```

But if i append a second `Select` the query doesn't works, see below:

```
INSERT INTO factmonitoreo (idEstacion, IdVariable, IdTiempoRegistro, Valor, ValorOriginal, FlagRegistro) 
(SELECT dt.idEstacion, dv.IdVariable, '2007-01-01 00:04:29', 0, 0, 0
FROM dimestacion AS dt 
INNER JOIN dimtipoestacion AS dte ON dt.IdTipoEstacion = dte.IdTipoEstacion 
JOIN dimvariable AS dv 
WHERE dt.Estacion LIKE 'El Lago' 
AND dte.CodTipoEstacion LIKE 'ECT' 
AND dv.ColumnNameToManualUpdateFromCSV LIKE 'Temperatura'),
(SELECT dt.idEstacion, dv.IdVariable, '2007-01-01 00:04:28', 0, 0, 0
FROM dimestacion AS dt 
INNER JOIN dimtipoestacion AS dte ON dt.IdTipoEstacion = dte.IdTipoEstacion 
JOIN dimvariable AS dv 
WHERE dt.Estacion LIKE 'El Lago' 
AND dte.CodTipoEstacion LIKE 'ECT' 
AND dv.ColumnNameToManualUpdateFromCSV LIKE 'Temperatura')
```

This piece of code raises the following error:

> [Code: 1064, SQL State: 42000]  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
> (SELECT dt.idEstacion, dv.IdVariable, '2007-01-01 00:04:28', 0, 0, 0
> FROM ...' at line 8  [Script position: 1792 - 1853]

I have read this documentation to do an attempt of insert with multiple selects:  [13.2.7.1 INSERT ... SELECT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: You can apply a `UNION ALL`, hence applying the `INSERT` on a single `SELECT` statement. Your query seems to be simplifiable tho, consider sharing some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it support multiple selects in a single insert statement. just split it into 2 sql, that will be fine...

Look at the [About This Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/manual-info.html#:%7E:text=%7C%20wild%5D-,An%20ellipsis,-(...)%20indicates) session,

The ellipsis in `SELECT ...` context is more like the omission of the statement.

Sometimes ellipsis will indicate the preceding element can be repeated. but usually it will be presented as `<element>, [<element>]...`